# Матрица (двумерный массив) в C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой компонент в виде таблицы можно использовать в C# Windows Forms для ввода/вывода матрицы? (Что-то вроде StringGrid'а в Delphi)

В гугле говорят, что для этого подходит DataGridView, но он довольно таки сложный, к тому же связанный с базами данных.

Comment: См. [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) (предшественник DataGridView), [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) в режиме `Details`, [ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx) со свойством `MultiColumn = true`, а также [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Огромное спасибо iluxa1810! Все работает)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй `DataGridView` в нем нет ничего сложного.

`DataGridView` универсален и служит для отображения любой коллекции и не только с БД.

Для того, что бы привязать к нему элементы нужна коллекция, например `List<T>`.

После того, как ты создал коллецию, ты делаешь:

`DataGridView.DataSource`=<твоя коллекция> и данные автоматически заносятся в таблицу.

Это самый простой вариант.

А вот с массивом придется немного повозится.

Например, есть массив string [,]mas размерностью NхM

```
dataGridView1.RowCount = N;
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = M;
int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    for(j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = mas[i, j];
```

На мой взгляд самое лучшее- это использовать коллекции.